# Normal gz file not extractable by tar

Tags: tar, compression, gzip

I have a gz archive but for some reason `tar` said that the format is incorrect even though I can double click it in mac Finder and extract it normally, and `file` command shows the same format just like any other tar.gz files

Why is that and how to extract it from the terminal?

```
$ file archive.gz
archive.gz: gzip compressed data, original size modulo 2^32 4327594

$ tar -xzf archive.gz
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format

$ tar --version
bsdtar 3.5.1 - libarchive 3.5.1 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.8
```

Comment: `gz`  is a compression format (often used to compress archives), not an archive format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compressed file is probably not a Tar archive.

You can find out the uncompressed filename with `gunzip -l archive.gz` - that might give you a clue as to the format.

If that doesn't work, then `gunzip` it, and use `file` on the uncompressed output.